# D7 Location module proximity search

Tags: search, users, location

I want be able to have users search for other users based on distance. I thought I did it correctly but everytime I search I get no results.

Heres what I did:

- Install location https://drupal.org/project/location
- Enabled location /w location entity, location search, location
  taxonomy, user locations
- Added location field to profile2 profile
- Ran the US zipcode file that comes with the location module
- Created a view to show profiles
- Added a relationship to location
- Added a filter of location proximity search based on zipcode and country /w a relation field_location

Comment: A solution would be to create a View of the users and have distance as an exposed filter.

Comment: I did that but always returns 0 results

Comment: I would have thought this would have worked for you. I used the [geofield](http://drupal.org/project/geofield) to have a location field in a content type and [ip_geoloc](https://drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) for mapping. This worked for me and I'll try and see if there is anything else required to help you.

Comment: I had to re add my users locations. Cause when they added their locations the zip DB was not loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every I did above was correct. I needed to have my users re-enter there location so geo-coding would be added to their profile.